# How to import current login user in to form by form.py Django

Tags: python, django

I want to automatically add the name of a logged in user to the form but i don't know how to import this varaible to the form

FILES >>>>

forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ArticleComment
        fields = ('user_name', 'body')

        widgets = {
            'user_name': forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'value': username }),
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        }
```

models.py

```
class ArticleComment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.post.title, self.user_name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article', args=(str(self.id)))
```

views.py

```
class AddCommentView(CreateView):
    model = ArticleComment
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = 'add_comment.html'
    # fields = '__all__'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['category_id']
        return super().form_valid(form)

    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ArticleComment model has the username set as a CharField, which means it is going to be expecting a string. I believe what you want to do is to set the user_name field of the CommentForm to the username of the currently logged-in user.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import ArticleComment


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ArticleComment
        fields = ('body', )

        widgets = {
            'user_name': forms.HiddenInput(), # remove attrs of the HiddenInput
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        }
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import ArticleComment, Article
from .forms import CommentForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


class AddCommentView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = ArticleComment
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = 'add_comment.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['category_id']
        form.instance.user_name = self.request.user.username # this sets the username field to the username of the currently logged in user
        return super().form_valid(form)


    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```